# How to use sklearn's standard scaler with make_pipeline?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, pipeline, training-data, test-data

I am used to running sklearn's **standard scaler** the following way:

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
scaler = StandardScaler().fit(X_train)
scaled_X_train = scaler.transform(X_train)
```

Where `X_train` is an array containing the features in my training dataset.

I may then use the same scaler to scale the features in my test dataset `X_test`:

```
scaled_X_test = scaler.transform(X_test)
```

I know that I may also "bake" the scaler in the model, using sklearn's `make_pipeline`:

```
from sklearn.pipeline import make_pipeline
clf = make_pipeline(preprocessing.StandardScaler(), RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=100))
```

But then **how do I use the scaler?** Is it enough to call the model like I normally would, *i.e.*:

```
clf.fit(X_train,y_train)
```

And then:

```
y_pred = clf.predict(X_test)
```

?

Comment: yes, that is correct. X_test will be scaled according to the fit in X_train, which is probably what you wanted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that is correct.
It's also a good idea to bake the preprocessing into a pipeline, to avoid the common pitfall of scaling the test and training datasets independently.

When calling `clf.fit(X_train,y_train)`, the pipeline will fit the Scaler on X_train, and subsequently use that fit to preprocess your test dataset.

See an example at the beginning of the "[common pitfalls and recommended practices](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/common_pitfalls.html)" documentation.

> We recommend using a Pipeline, which makes it easier to chain transformations with estimators, and reduces the possibility of forgetting a transformation.

So the fact that you don't "use" the Scaler yourself is per design.

With that said, if you wanted for some reason to independently access the scaler from a pipeline, for example to check it's values, you could do so:

```py
clf.fit(X_train,y_train)
# For example, get the first step of the pipeline steps[0]
# then get the actual scaler object [1]
clf.steps[0][1].scale_
```

Comment: Thanks also for sending the link to the pitfalls and recommended practices.

Comment: I agree that it would be safer to include all preprocessing steps into the pipeline. I have a bunch of homebrew (*i.e.* not scikit-learn) preprocessing steps (*e.g* smoothing, despiking) to apply to my data and I don't know yet how to include them to the `make_pipeline`.

Comment: write an interface for them deriving from the `BaseEstimator` class and implement a fit and a transform method. See https://scikit-learn.org/stable/developers/develop.html?highlight=baseestimator